# baffled by output result from strftime()

Tags: c, date, time

After closely looking at time.h more than a few times I wrote the following func :

```
void output_date ( int day, int month, int year ) {
    char buffer[64] = "";
    struct tm *e_time = calloc( (size_t) 1, sizeof(struct tm) );

    e_time->tm_year = year - 1900;
    e_time->tm_mon = month - 1;
    e_time->tm_mday = day;
    e_time->tm_hour = 0;
    e_time->tm_min = 0;
    e_time->tm_sec = 0;
    e_time->tm_isdst = -1;

    /* strftime ( buffer, 64, (char *)0, e_time ); */
    strftime ( buffer, 64, "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z (%z) %Y", e_time );

    printf ( "%s\n", buffer );

    free(e_time);
    e_time = NULL;

}
```

I then called this function with a range of possible inputs and saw nothing but
bizarre output like so :

```
Sun Jul  8 00:00:00  () 2013
Sun Jul  9 00:00:00  () 2013
Sun Jul 10 00:00:00  () 2013
Sun Jul 11 00:00:00  () 2013
Sun Jul 12 00:00:00  () 2013
```

When I test my format string to strftime I see good results thus :

```
$ date -u "+%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z (%z) %Y"
Sat Oct 12 00:40:05 GMT (+0000) 2013
```

I even went so far as to single step via a debugger and saw the same
bizarre results :

```
stopped in main at line 27 in file "flight.c"
   27                       output_date ( day+1, month+1, year );
(dbx) print day+1, month+1, year
day+1 = 1
month+1 = 1
year = 1977

(dbx) step                      
stopped in output_date at line 43 in file "flight.c"
   43       char buffer[64] = "";
(dbx) step
stopped in output_date at line 44 in file "flight.c"
   44       struct tm *e_time = calloc( (size_t) 1, sizeof(struct tm) );
(dbx) step
stopped in output_date at line 46 in file "flight.c"
   46       e_time->tm_year = year - 1900;
(dbx) print e_time
e_time = 0x100101640
(dbx) step        
stopped in output_date at line 47 in file "flight.c"
   47       e_time->tm_mon = month - 1;
(dbx) step
stopped in output_date at line 48 in file "flight.c"
   48       e_time->tm_mday = day;
(dbx) step
stopped in output_date at line 49 in file "flight.c"
   49       e_time->tm_hour = 0;
(dbx) step
stopped in output_date at line 50 in file "flight.c"
   50       e_time->tm_min = 0;
(dbx) step
stopped in output_date at line 51 in file "flight.c"
   51       e_time->tm_sec = 0;
(dbx) step
stopped in output_date at line 52 in file "flight.c"
   52       e_time->tm_isdst = -1;
(dbx) step
stopped in output_date at line 55 in file "flight.c"
   55       strftime ( buffer, 64, "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z (%z) %Y", e_time );
(dbx) print *e_time
*e_time = {
    tm_sec   = 0
    tm_min   = 0
    tm_hour  = 0
    tm_mday  = 1
    tm_mon   = 0
    tm_year  = 77
    tm_wday  = 0
    tm_yday  = 0
    tm_isdst = -1
}
(dbx) step        
stopped in output_date at line 57 in file "flight.c"
   57       printf ( "%s\n", buffer );
(dbx) print buffer
buffer = "Sun Jan  1 00:00:00  () 1977"
(dbx) quit
```

In fact, all I ever get is a day of the week being Sunday and the correct month
with the correct day and year.  Not much else seems correct.

Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: What compiler and OS?

Comment: Thus far I have tried Debian Linux 7.1 with gcc 4.7.2 and also Solaris 10 with Oracle Studio 12.  On Solaris I see the above result. On Linux I get a segfault.  Sorry .. was getting a segfault ... now I get just a weird result.

Comment: It segfaults on ideone.com too...

Comment: Just fyi... http://ideone.com/QpUguN is a test on ideone.  Also, look at the ideone code.  There is no need to call `calloc` and `free` like you've done here.  You're burning cycles for nothing.  Calling `memset` on `e_time` is enough to avoid the segfault but doesn't make the output complete.

Comment: I was flailing a bit trying to figure out where I went wrong.  The calloc and then free with a set to NULL was just evidence of "flail". In truth I could just use an ordinary variable on the heap.

Comment: Just trying to help... ` In truth I could just use an ordinary variable on the heap.` %s/heap/stack/

Comment: yep .. stack is what I meant. I confuse the terms all the time but know the diff between a dynamically allocated and not ... anyways .. working well now and I can confirm that "Mon Feb 29 00:00:00 GMT (+0000) 1988" was a leap day.  Not that I was looking for leap days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the field `tm_isdst` the value of `-1`, which means the daylight saving time is not available, change it to `1` if the daylight saving time is in effect, or `0` if it's not.

As @Paul Griffiths points out, calling `mktime(e_time)` is the better option here, the `mktime` function will fill the broken down `e_time`, as it will fix the fileds like `tm_wday` and `tm_day` as well. For the field of `tm_isdst`, it follows this rule:

> a positive or zero value for `tm_isdst` causes the `mktime` function to presume initially that Daylight Saving Time, respectively, is or is not in effect for the specified time. A negative value causes it to attempt to determine whether Daylight Saving Time is in effect for the specified time.

Comment: `-1` also means that `mktime()` should attempt to discover whether DST is in effect, which is usually what you want to do.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Yes, I've already added that part, that is a better solution. Fixing `tm_isdst` manually will work as well if that information is available.

Comment: I may have to deal with a wide range of input dates and so the dst data just isn't avail.  I simply didn't see the mktime() call as a need.  In fact ... I didn't see any mention of it in manpages.  This is clearly one of those things one must just *know*.

Comment: In this case, when he's trying to print out the day of the week and timezone information, I wouldn't count on manually setting `tm_isdst` being sufficient without calling `mktime()` and leaving members like `tm_wday` uninitialized (or set to `0`, in this case, due to the `calloc()` call, which is why it's showing Sunday all the time).

Comment: @paullanken In that case, `mktime` is what you need. The words I quoted is from the C standard, maybe you should check on that.

Comment: I may need to get the name of the day of the week from a date in 1977 or possibly 1952.  Daylight Savings Time information just won't be available and I thought the -1 was a safe way to go.  Turns out I was given yet another great opportunity at humility and education :-)

Comment: @PaulGriffiths You are right, `mktime` is the better option here.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `mktime(e_time)` after populating your struct, but before calling `strftime()`. You have some other struct members that are not currently being completed. Passing a struct with uninitialized values (or initialized to incorrect values, here, due to your `calloc()` call) is generally a Bad Thing to do, and `mktime()` modifies the struct you pass to fill them in for you.

Like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void output_date ( int day, int month, int year ) {
    char buffer[64] = "";
    struct tm *e_time = calloc( (size_t) 1, sizeof(struct tm) );

    e_time->tm_year = year - 1900;
    e_time->tm_mon = month - 1;
    e_time->tm_mday = day;
    e_time->tm_hour = 0;
    e_time->tm_min = 0;
    e_time->tm_sec = 0;
    e_time->tm_isdst = -1;

    if ( mktime(e_time) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error getting calendar time.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int n = strftime ( buffer, 64, "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z (%z) %Y", e_time );
    printf("Return from strftime() is %d\n", n);

    printf ( "%s\n", buffer );

    free(e_time);
    e_time = NULL;

}

int main(void) {
    output_date(12, 6, 2013);
    return 0;
}
```

yields:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./st
Return from strftime() is 36
Wed Jun 12 00:00:00 EDT (-0400) 2013
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

Comment: whoa!  I just checked the manpage on mktime and it looks to return a time_t type object.  Sorry, not an object but a datatype.  Also, seems to do a whack of cool stuff.  OKay .. let me try that good Sir!

Comment: @paullanken: Yes, it does, but in your case, you don't need to use it, other than to check the return which you always should. The key thing here is that `mktime()` modifies the `struct tm` that you pass to it.